# socket.io and node.js not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to practice creating apps with socket.io and node.js. This is a simple "log in" app, but it doesn't seem to be working, whenever I start the app a 404 not found message pops up on the chrome developer console with this adress: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1469215104245-2

in my index.hjs file

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control username" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control password" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<h2></h2>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();
      $('.btn-primary').click(function(){
        var data  = {username: $('.username').val(), password: $('.password').val()};
        socket.emit('log-in',data);

        socket.on('log-in success', function(){
            $('h2').append('success')
        });
      socket.on('log-in fail', function(){
            $('h2').append('fail')
        });


      });


</script>
```

on my node js server (there is more code there but these are the rlevant bits):

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);


io.on('log-in',function(data){
  User.findOne({ 'username': data.username, 'password': data.password}, function (err, person) {
    if (err) {io.emit('log-in fail')
      return handleError(err)};
    if (!person) io.emit('log-in success');
  })
});
```

Whenever I try to log in as a premade user just don't get any response back.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't listen to messages from a given connection on the server with `io.on()`.  Instead, you do this where you listen for a given socket connecting and then you add event handlers to that specific socket and when you want to send back to that socket, you also use that `socket` object to send back to.  This allows you to send back to the same socket that just sent you a message:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('log-in', function (data) {
        User.findOne({'username': data.username, 'password': data.password}, function (err, person) {
            if (err) {
                socket.emit('log-in fail')
                return handleError(err)
            };
            if (!person) socket.emit('log-in success');
        })
    });
});
```

But, you may also want to know that there's a framework for socket.io connection authentication that makes it a little more of a built-in part of accepting a connection.  You can do your own like this if you want, but it will likely have some issues you haven't thought of.

P.S. This logic looks a bit flawed to me.  If you find the person in your database, you emit no response on the socket.